# Letter shared by many words

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word describing the sharing of an object (for example a letter) by other objects (for example words) such as:

- The **B** in *Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid* as shared on the 3-dimensional ambigram on the [book's cover](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/GEBcover.jpg).
- The **A** in this game of [Scrabble](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Scrabble_2.jpg).
- The **I** shared by *WIKI* and *IGOR* in this [crossword](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/WikiKwadratMagiczny.jpg) puzzle.

Comment: I wish I could give this question infinitive votes and favorites...

Answer (score 4):

In crossword lingo, a shared letter is "doubly checked".  There are instances where the letter might be shared with more than two clues, as the circled letters in [this puzzle](http://rexwordpuzzle.blogspot.com/2011/05/cephalopod-known-for-its-shell-wed-5-11.html), and they would be "triply checked", or "quadruply checked", etc.

Comment: That is a fitting answer to the crossword and Scrabble part, but the _GEB:EGB_ example was really the reason I asked and I don't feel like “doubly checked” is descriptive of that — there may yet be a better word!

Comment: @Iceland_jack: I agree.

Answer (score 2):

You would be hard-pressed to find an answer that is "one key to every lock", but the word that you could be looking for is "overlapping" or "Intersecting" words.